# Find the value of the given series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

If $\sum_{r=1}^nf(r)=n(2n^2+9n+13)$, then find the value of $$\sum_{r=1}^{12}\sqrt f(r)$$
A) $76\sqrt 6$

B) $80\sqrt 6$

C) $90\sqrt 6$

D) $81\sqrt 2$

Comment: This is "stackexchange", not "do my homework". Did you try _anything_ yourself?

Comment: I tried to take the n inside brackets and applied the summations of n^3,n^2 and n.But it didn't lead to any result.

Comment: Using $n = 1$, can you tell me what $f(1)$ is? Using $n = 2$, can you tell me what $f(2)$ is?

Comment: You can compute $f(1)=1(2+9+13)=24$ and $f(1)+f(2)=78$ thus $f(2)=78-24=54$ and so on to compute the values $f(1)$ to $f(12)$ then You add the roots $\sqrt{24}+\sqrt{54}$ ...

Comment: I can do this but it is competition exam based Question.There should be a short method to this question.I am just searching for that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Since
$$
\sum_{r=1}^nf(r)=n(2n^2+9n+13)
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
f(n)
&=n(2n^2+9n+13)-(n-1)(2(n-1)^2+9(n-1)+13)\\
&=6n^2+12n+6\\
&=6(n+1)^2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Since you are given that $$\sum_{r=1}^nf(r)=n(2n^2+9n+13)$$ then $$f(r)=a+b r+c r^2$$ So, $$\sum_{r=1}^nf(r)=a \sum_{r=1}^n 1+b\sum_{r=1}^n r+ c \sum_{r=1}^nr^2=a n +\frac{b}{2} n (n+1)+\frac{c}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1)$$ Identify $a,b,c$ and you will get a nice expression for $f(r)$ and also for $\sqrt{f(r)}$.

I am sure that you can easily take it from here.

Comment: Wouldn't $f(n)=s(n)-s(n-1)$ with $s(n)=n(2n^2+9n+13)$ be simpler?

Comment: @ProfessorVector. You are right, for sure ! I was just trying to provide another way after the comments.